# Given $ x^5 + x = 10 $ show that A. It has only one root. B. The root lies between 1 and 2 and C. The root is irrational

Tags: polynomials, irrational-numbers

So the first two are easy. 
The third one is the one that's tricky.
So I tried assuming that the root is rational and let it be $p/q$ but I couldn't go any further or make real progress.
More over it's a undergrad entrance question so it won't use really hard math.

Comment: Have you heard of the rational root test? At least forty years ago it was in my high school material. Applied to this equation it says that an eventual rational root must be an integer.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen but in question he is asking for irrational roots?

Comment: @TheStudent That's exactly what that test would allow them to conclude - there aren't any rational roots.

Comment: And please include the question in the body. Having it in the title in telegram style is a disservice.

Comment: The correct statement of the question is "It has only one **real** root".

Answer (score 3):

**C.**  We want to show that the solution to $$x^5+x=10$$ is irrational.  To do that, we can let $f(x)=x^5+x-10$.  Since the constant is $-10$ and the leading coefficient is $1$, we know the only potential rational roots are $\pm1, \pm2, \pm5$, or $\pm10$ (i.e. a rational number in the form $\pm\frac{p}{q}$, where $p|10$ and $q|1$).  Since the value of the function is non-zero for each of these potential rational roots, we conclude that the root must be irrational.

---

For a complete solution to the three questions:

**A.**  We want to show that $$x^5+x=10$$ has only one real solution.  To do that, we can let $f(x)=x^5+x-10$.  We know that odd degree polynomial functions will have at least one real root.  Observe that $f'(x)>0\ \forall x\in\Bbb R\implies f(x)$ is strictly increasing.  This shows that $f(x)$ has only one real solution.

**B.**  We want to show that $$x^5+x=10$$ has a solution on the interval $[1,2]$.  To do that, we can let $f(x)=x^5+x-10$.  Observe that $f(1)=-8$ and $f(2)=24$.  By the intermediate value theorem, since $f(x)$ is continuous on the interval $[1,2]$, we have some $c\in[1,2]$ that satisfies $f(1)<f(c)<f(2)$.  In other words, there must exist some $c\in[1,2]$ such that $f(c)=0$, since $-8<0<24$.